# react-Native get create-Date for a Photo

Tags: react-native, photo, camera-roll

I want to sort the pictures by date,   so I need the creation-date. from where can I get this date?

in the Gallery my photos are sorted for this. 
I want sort Photos like this on my app.

I want to continue using the CameraRoll.

thanks